# How can I call a method from itself inside a class?

Tags: javascript, class

I'm currently implementing a WebSocket. Because I want to reconnect when the connection get's closed, I've implemented a `connect()` function and tried to call it inside the close event from itself but unfortunately it's not working:

```
class WebSocket {
    constructor( options = {} ) {
        this.url = "ws://localhost:8181";

        this.connect();
    }

    connect() {
        let ws = new WebSocket( this.url );

        ws.onclose = function ( event ) {
            console.log( `WebSocket connection to ${ this.url } failed: ${ event.reason }` );

            setTimeout( function () {
                connect();
            }, 5000 );
        };
    }
}
```

The thrown error is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: connect is not defined
```

I've never worked with classes in JavaScript so I'm a bit confused. Maybe someone can give me a hint?

Comment: `connect` is not a standalone variable name, it's a property on the instance (well, its prototype)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Okay! And how should I do this right?

Comment: Is your class really named `WebSocket`? When instantiated once, It'll call itself recursively resulting in a stack overflow. Is your `let ws = new WebSocket( this.url );` attempting to refer to `window.WebSocket` instead?

Comment: Nope. It's just the name of my class but I'll rename it. What I originally wanted to do is to reconnect after the connection drops. For that I need to call connect every 5 seconds for example from inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Because `this` refers to `ws.onclose`, I need to safe this instantly at the top of my function:

```
class Connector {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        this.url = "ws://localhost:8181";
        this.connect();
    }
    connect() {
        const ws = new WebSocket(this.url),
              self = this;

        ws.onclose = (event) => {
            console.log(`WebSocket connection to ${ this.url } failed: ${ event.reason }`);
            setTimeout(() => {
                self.connect();
            }, 5000);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues:

- To reference a property of an object, use `.`, eg `obj.prop`. Here, the object on which a property you want to reference is the instance, `this`.
- You need to make sure `this` refers to the class instance inside the `setTimeout`, so use arrow functions
- The `WebSocket` class name clashes with the lexically scoped `globalThis.Websocket` property - name your class something else:

```
class Connector {
  constructor(options = {}) {
    this.url = "ws://localhost:8181";
    this.connect();
  }
  connect() {
    const ws = new WebSocket(this.url);
    ws.onclose = (event) => {
      console.log(`WebSocket connection to ${ this.url } failed: ${ event.reason }`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.connect();
      }, 5000);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Still says `Uncaught TypeError: this.connect is not a function`

Comment: Works just fine here, see here for a live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1xvmjc2w/